# How do I test the fallback component for the ErrorBoundary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-error-boundary

I have this component:

```js
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { ErrorBoundary } from '../ErrorBoundary';

const FALLBACK = <svg aria-label="" data-testid="icon-fallback" viewBox="0 0 21 21" />;

const ERROR = (
    <svg data-testid="icon-notdef" viewBox="0 0 21 21">
        <path d="M0.5,0.5v20h20v-20H0.5z M9.1,10.5l-6.6,6.6V3.9L9.1,10.5z M3.9,2.5h13.2l-6.6,6.6L3.9,2.5z M10.5,11.9l6.6,6.6H3.9 L10.5,11.9z M11.9,10.5l6.6-6.6v13.2L11.9,10.5z" />
    </svg>
);

export const Icon = ({ ariaLabel, ariaHidden, name, size }) => {
    const LazyIcon = lazy(() => import(`../../assets/icons/${size}/${name}.svg`));
    return (
        <i aria-hidden={ ariaHidden }>
            <ErrorBoundary fallback={ ERROR }>
                <Suspense fallback={ FALLBACK }>
                    <LazyIcon aria-label={ ariaLabel } data-testid="icon-module" />
                </Suspense>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </i>
    );
};
```

I’m trying to test the condition where an SVG is passed in that doesn’t exist, in turn rendering the `<ErrorBoundary />` fallback. The ErrorBoundary works in the browser, but not in my test.

This is the failing test:

```js
test('shows notdef icon', async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Icon name='doesnt-exist' />);
    const iconModule = await waitFor(() => getByTestId('icon-notdef'));
    expect(iconModule).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I get this error message:

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="icon-notdef"]”.

How do I access ErrorBoundary fallback UI in my test?

#### Edit

This is the code for the `<ErrorBoundary />` component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: '',
            errorInfo: '',
            hasError: false,
        };
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
        return { hasError: true, error };
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
        console.error({ error, errorInfo });
        this.setState({ error, errorInfo });
    }

    render() {
        const { children, fallback } = this.props;
        const { error, errorInfo, hasError } = this.state;

        // If there is an error AND a fallback UI is passed in…
        if (hasError && fallback) {
            return fallback;
        }

        // Otherwise if there is an error with no fallback UI…
        if (hasError) {
            return (
                <details className="error-details">
                    <summary>There was an error.</summary>
                    <p style={ { margin: '12px 0 0' } }>{error && error.message}</p>
                    <pre>
                        <code>
                            {errorInfo && errorInfo.componentStack.toString()}
                        </code>
                    </pre>
                </details>
            );
        }

        // Finally, render the children.
        return children;
    }
}

ErrorBoundary.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.array]).isRequired,
    fallback: PropTypes.node,
};
```

… and this is the full error with DOM that I get for the test:

```
shows notdef icon

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="icon-notdef"]

    <body>
      <div>
        <i
          aria-hidden="false"
          class="Icon Icon--sm"
        >
          <span
            aria-label=""
            data-testid="icon-module"
          />
        </i>
      </div>
    </body>

    <html>
      <head />
      <body>
        <div>
          <i
            aria-hidden="false"
            class="Icon Icon--sm"
          >
            <span
              aria-label=""
              data-testid="icon-module"
            />
          </i>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>Error: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="icon-notdef"]
```

Lastly, my SVG mock:

```js
import React from 'react';

const SvgrMock = React.forwardRef(
    function mySVG(props, ref) {
        return <span { ...props } ref={ ref } />;
    },
);

export const ReactComponent = SvgrMock;
export default SvgrMock;
```

Comment: Could you add the code for your `ErrorBoundary` component to the question?

Comment: Also, what does the DOM look like during the test? You can use [`debug()` from RTL](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#debug) to check.

Comment: Added further detail, @juliomalves!

Comment: So if the an element with `data-testid="icon-module"` gets rendered that means it's not erroring at all? Could it be the SVG mock interfering?

Comment: @juliomalves — I’m honestly not sure. I’ve tried to replicate on Codesandbox and haven’t been able to.

Comment: How are you using your SVG mock? If you don't mock the SVGs, do you still get the issue?

Comment: If it helps, I had to do some very similar tests for my own library, feel free to [reference them for inspiration](https://github.com/patrickroberts/suspense-service/blob/master/src/__tests__/Service.test.tsx). I opted to use `react-test-renderer` directly though rather than `react-testing-library`.

Comment: What mechanism are you using for mocking svg files? you need to know a way to revert it and do it in that single test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it is most likely the mock is avoiding the error. Try re mocking the SVG files with a new mock throwing an error.

```
// tests that require unmocking svg files
describe('non existent svg', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.mock('.svg', () => {
      throw new Error('file not found')
    });
  });
  
  test('shows notdef icon', async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Icon name='doesnt-exist' />);
    const iconModule = await waitFor(() => getByTestId('icon-notdef'));
    expect(iconModule).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  afterAll(() => jest.unmock('.svg'))
})
```

It is necessary to wrap it to ensure the SVG files are re-mocked only during the test (`beforeAll` - `afterAll`) to not interfere with the rest of the tests.

Comment: We’re on to something here! If I remove the mock from config and run just this test, it passes! But if I reenable the mock and add `jest.unmock('../../../test/__mocks__/svg.js');` at the beginning of the test it fails as it did before.

Comment: @BrandonDurham did you try with the path in the answer? `../../assets/icons/sm/doesnt-exist.svg`

Comment: I sure did. Fails in the same way.

Comment: @BrandonDurham, I updated my answer assuming you're using the `moduleNameMapper` option in jest config. I tried it, and it worked

Comment: That particular regex didn’t work, but this one did: `'^(?!.*(doesnt-exist)).*svg$': '<rootDir>/test/__mocks__/svg.js',` Not a great idea to put this in config, though, is it?

Comment: @BrandonDurham definitely not. I'll try another approach later today

Comment: @BrandonDurham I updated the answer with a new approach, it's a little verbose, but you could make a utility function if you're testing unexisting SVG files somewhere else